# Git, ¿Alguna forma de volver atras?

Tags: git

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de clase, y al ir a hacer un push del trabajo de toda la tarde me he encontrado con esto...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He buscado "fatal: You are not currently on a branch" en google y he encontrado esto...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Línea por línea he seguido los pasos sin acabar de entender lo que estaba haciendo, y al terminar me encuentro con que al hacer un "git log", el commit más reciente que veo es de las 13h (hace 12h, mas o menos).

Al hacer Git Status veo esto..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Parece que me he cargado todo el trabajo de hoy...¿existe alguna forma de recuperarlo?

Gracias.

Comment: Si haces git status, que te dice? hay unos videos muy bueno en youtube que te permitiria entender los comandos. Son sencillos de entender

Comment: Edito la pregunta para ponerte la captura

Comment: Tenes un tutorial para comprender mejor lo que hiciste y debes hacer ahora en adelante. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HiXLkL42tMU

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En git es difícil perder cambios que hallan sido commiteados.
Cuando uno commitea pasan algunas cosas:

- se crea un commit nuevo, que es hijo del commit actual
- el branch actual, que es simplemente una etiqueta o referencia que apunta a un commit, se actualiza para apuntar al nuevo commit
- lo antererior tambien sucede para la etiqueta HEAD, que representa la referencia (commit y/o branch) sobre la cual estas parado en este momento

Hasta donde se, la unica manera de perder un commit para siempre es asegurarse de que ningun branch lo referencie, y correr `git prune`.

Mas seguro que no, tus cambios todavia estan en tu computadora. Podes buscarlos usando `git reflog`.

Este es un ejemplo del output de `git reflog`:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Busca el ultimo commit que creaste, y al que quedrias volver y copia su SHA.
Una vez que encuentres el commit que contiene tu valioso trabajo, podes resetear master para apuntar a ese commit.

```sh
git checkout master

# (Opcional) Si tienes cambios en el cache (no commiteados) que no quieras perder ...
git stash # ... guardalos en el stash

# Cuidado, cualquier cambio que no este commiteado se va a perder!
git reset --hard commit_id --

# (Opcional) Y ahora podes sacar los cambios que guardaste en el stash
git stash pop
```

Si todo salio bien, cuando corras `git log`, deberia mostrarte que la etiqueta `master` apunta al commit que querias.

Comment: Maravilloso! Pero al hacer "git reset --hard b5def08" me dice "ambiguous argument 'b5def08' both revision and filename"...aun así, ya respiso aliviado de que esto tenga solución!!!

Comment: "ambiguous argument 'b5def08' both revision and filename" significant que b5def08 es tanto el nombre de un archivo actual en tu directorio de trabajo como el de una referencia de git. El pantallazo que subiste muestra que por alguna razon tenes un archivo con ese nombre. Si no lo necesitas, borralo. En todo caso, para que git entiende que lo que le estamos pasando es una referencia y no un archivo, podes poner ' -- ' al final del comando

Comment: He escrito...git reset --hard <b5def08> # .... y no ha dicho nada. Como que todo esta bien. Pero al hacer "git log" sigo sin ver mis ultimos commits. Me da miedo tocar nada si no me lo dice alguien como tu, que sepa.

Comment: finalmente resuelto siguiendo las instrucciones de "Nicooga". Mi error, otro mas, era que estaba copiando su sugerencia "git reset --hard <commit_id>" incluyendo los caracteres "<>", cosa que no había que hacer. Espero que esto ayude a alguien en un futuro y se sienta, como mínimo, tan aliviado como me siento yo ahora mismo. Muchas gracias Nicooga!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Puedes regresar de varias formas algunas mas peligrosas que otras por ejemplo:

1.-Puedes volver con :

```
git checkout + id del commit al que quieres regresar
```

este tambien es una forma de crear ramas y moverte entre ellas.

2.-con git reset no solo regresas si no que también borras los cambios que se hicieron después de este commit,Se usa de dos formas:

`git reset -hard borra` toda la informacion en el area de staing.

```
git reset -soft  Manteniendo la informacion en el area de staing.
```

Tambien debes saber que el comando git reset es un comando peligroso y no debe usarse sin uno de sus flags (--soft,--hard,--HEAD).Ya que una vez usado no hay vuelta atrás.
git checkout es como una maquina del tiempo nos deja ir ,mirar ,pasear ,volver.

Documentación oficial:

[git checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)

[git reset](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset)